# How to get element from DOM and set onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html element:

```
<table id="miniToolbar">
     <tbody>          
        <tr><td>
          <button id="btnStrView" type="button" onclick='parent.ExecuteCommand()' class="button_air-medium">
            <img id="streetView" class="miniToolbarContant" src="../stdicons/streetview-icon.png"></button>
          </td></tr> 
    <tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see inside button I have on click event:

```
onclick='parent.ExecuteCommand()'
```

And I have this JS function:

```
function isMenuItemMasked(item)
{
    var funcId = '75';

     var elem = document.getElementById('btnStrView');

    return false;
}
```

as you can see inside function I have variable called funcId.

I need to put this funcId to the on click event:

```
onclick='parent.ExecuteCommand('75')'
```

After I fetch element and put it inside elem variable how do I put  `funcId` as parameter to `parent.ExecuteCommand()`?

Comment: might be better to use `addEventListener` in case like this. `elem.addEventListener('click', function() { parent.ExecuteCommand(funcId ) });`

Comment: Where is your ExecuteCommand method ? <td> is parent so use <td onclick="ExecuteCommand()"

Comment: You can define the `funcId`  variable outside the function. So `onclick='parent.ExecuteCommand( funcId )`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to set the function argument dynamically. Without using external libraries I would do as follows:

```js
function runSubmit() {
  var value = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("run").addEventListener('click', function() {
    func(value);
  });
}

function func(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Setup Param" onclick="runSubmit()">
<input id="run" type="submit" value="Run with param">
```

<sup>**How to use this:** When you run the snippet, you will see a text input, a Setup Param button and a Run with param button. Insert something in the text input and click Setup Param. After, click on Run with param to see the effect</sup>

The input text contains the string that will be used as parameter for `func(value)`. The update of `#run` button callback is triggered by the "Setup param", through the `runSubmit()` callback. This callback adds to the `#run` element a listener for the `'click'` event, that runs a function with the parameter fixed when event occurs.

This is only a MCVE, you should adapt it to your case scenario.

Mh... Actually @jacob-goh gave you this exact solution in a comment while I wrote this...

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to call you function from inside the function and pass your variable to that function.

```
function isMenuItemMasked(item)
{
 var funcId = "75";

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnStrView").click(function(){
   parent.ExecuteCommand(funcId);
 });
});
}
function ExecuteCommand(your_var){
    alert(your_var);
    //your code
    }
```